# What is the short in which a man has a nightmare complete with broken physics?

Tags: identify-this-movie, short-films

It's been at least two years now since bits of a movie short started echoing around in my head and I'd like to get them  out. I've searched using every term I can think of and can't root out the clip. It might not even be a short, there is a good chance it  was a music video. All of the details below are subject to my imagination and poor memory, but as best as I can...

The scenes are animated and hazy, the palette is dark and muted. The soundtrack is lively and possibly French or other non-English. A man has a nightmare in which he wakes up and everything is broken. He follows a sound, looking for or following something, but the world around him does nothing but play him dirty tricks. Physics especially is no friend. He goes through a a door and gravity changes directions, he falls into a mirror and clashes through an atrium. There is water in various scenes, and at some point I think he gets into a fight.  Or narrowly misses being decked  or something. Maybe he sees bad guys around a corner? At some point he stops his following or searching and tries to make his way back, then eventually wakes up or something.

That's about all. But the feeling of "what *was* that" won't leave. The closest thing I've come across is the brilliant [Le Café short](http://youtu.be/UGtKGX8B9hU) which my gut instinct tells me is about the same genre. Other ones I've run across in the hunt that are similar in visual style even though the themes are different are [Matter Fisher](http://youtu.be/nEgOK0WyDj4), [Lifeline](http://youtu.be/m01y5viJJpA), [Hum](http://youtu.be/DIri3-M-BTo) and even the strange and disturbing [Luica](http://youtu.be/FGj74CRn8xo) and [Luis](http://youtu.be/veMBIWv0ews) shorts. [Contamination](http://youtu.be/XfAKFAnm0JU) and [Suprise](http://youtu.be/hbb0jPZlFMU) also has a similar palettes. But none of these are "it". Nor is this going to be a feature film [The Science of Sleep](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0354899/?ref_=nv_sr_1) or an advertisement like the [Adidas commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbBNScrYN10).

But what do I know anyway? Maybe the nightmare was mine and there never was such a short. Maybe I had too much coffee that day and watched something else and just imagined it all.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like an old Adidas commercial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbBNScrYN10

It has the gravity changing element, and almost getting attacked (by a bear).  I doubt this is it, but if it is, let me know and I'll put it as an answer.

Comment: @Liesmith That's hillarious, but no definitely not it. What I am thinking of is definitely cartoon rendered and not nearly so positive. That's hardly a nightmare, bear or no.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might've just been a quality of being half-remembered (because who pays close attention to commercials?); I'm curious to find out the answer, it sounds interesting as hell.

Comment: Reminds me of the some levels on Alan Wake!!

Comment: @Dredd Nope, definitely not.

Comment: It was a long shot anyway.

Comment: Any chance it was 
Jan Svankmajer's surreal [*Byt*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062770/combined)? Some of it fits your description. You can watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pjc3nsTSPIk).

Answer (score 4):

Is it [The Science of sleep (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0354899/?ref_=nv_sr_1).
The reason I believe it is this movie is that it is also **part french**. The guy goes to sleep and weird things happen. He sees the world in his own way and his **dreams defy the normal laws of physics**. There is **definitely water** in the movie since he uses water (with alarm clock) to wake himself up. Apart from that, there are also **several fight scenes**(though funny).It also had a little touch of **animation** to it.It matches most of the details provided above but I am not sure.

Comment: This is a great guess. The script could have been written from my question—but unfortunately it's not it. The thing I'm thinking of is animated and definitely a short, not a feature length film. I've reviewed this film and it's not it.

Comment: +1 and bounty awarded because this was a good effort (and I don't want the bounty to go to waste even if I didn't get exactly what I was fishing for).